# Angular 2 : how to open ngx-popover programmatically

Tags: angular, typescript, popover

I am using [ngx-popover](https://github.com/pleerock/ngx-popover) I am trying to open it from another component by clicking button

secondcomponent.html

```
<button popover #ChatPopover=popover (click)="ClickElement()">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span>
                        </button>
```

secondcomponent.ts

```
ClickElement() {

   this.div = document.getElementById("ChatPopover")
   console.log(this.div);

}
```

popoverelement.html

```
<div class="chat" name="chatwindow">
            <div [ng2-draggable]="true">
                <popover-content #ChatPopover
                                 placement="right"
                                 [animation]="true"
                                 [closeOnClickOutside]="true">


                    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="ChatPopover.hide()">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <h5 style="color:#D25C50">Chat</h5>

                </popover-content>
            </div>
       </div>
```

Here secondcomponent is not a direct child component of popovercomponent. so I tried to implement through document getelementbyId, from this I'm getting popover reference but popover is not coming.

Answer (score 2):

Hope it's not too late to this question.

1. Define your popover directive

```html
<a [routerLink]="null" #popoverDirective="popover" [popover]="selectorPopover" popoverPlacement="top" container="body"></a>
```

2. Reference to your popover directive like this
   @ViewChild('**popoverDirective**') popoverDirective: PopoverDirective;
3. Then in your code show or hide popover
   this.popoverDirective.show();
   this.popoverDirective.hide();

Answer (score 0):

To programmatically handle the popover, just declare the ViewChild like below.

In your `.ts` file:

```
import { Popover } from 'ngx-popover';

@ViewChild("myPopover") myPopover : Popover;

showPopover(){
    this.myPopover.hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, and here is my code, hope it would help.

```js
 @ViewChild('menuPopover')
 private popover: PopoverDirective;
 
 ......
 
 setConfigObject(imei:string, period: any):void{
    this.popover.hide();
    ...
  }
```

```html
<a class="deviceAtag" [popover]="popover" placement="right" [outsideClick]="true" #menuPopover="bs-popover">{{item.devicename}}</a>
<ng-template #popover>... </ng-template>
```

I use angular7.
I suppose the point is you should **export your popover element as "bs-popover" type object**, so that the object can be accessed from your angular code.

if you bump into another similar problem with ngx-bootstrap usage, i think you can find your answer from their homepage, because every api reference told what the element should be exported as.

[screenshot from the homepage reference where you can find the "exported as" description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hddkb.png)